# Spring Autowiring at class initialization

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Could the Autowiring using @Autowired spring annotation happen at class initialization, and not just before constructor call ? thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate [how-does-autowiring-work-in-spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153546/how-does-autowiring-work-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Ass described here: https://blog.jdriven.com/2015/03/spicy-spring-different-ways-of-autowiring/:

**Constructor Autowiring**

**Method Autowiring**

with this ways of inject dependencies you have more control over the logic you want to apply during a bean initialization.

Answer (score 0):

To elucidate on what rperes said, the InjectableBean is being injected at construction, but if you have not configured InjectableBean as a component to be injected, then you will have problems.

Check that your configuration for InjectableBean is correct. Have a look at [Spring: Properly setup @ComponentScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857770/spring-properly-setup-componentscan)